# Iterate over dates in R: why it cast Date to numeric?

Tags: r, loops, date

I was wondering why R casts class `Date` into numeric when iterating over an array of `Date`s.

```
dates = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03"))
for(i in 1:3) print(dates[i]) #Print Dates
[1] "2017-01-01"
[1] "2017-01-02"
[1] "2017-01-03"
for(d in dates) print(d) #Cast dates into numeric
[1] 17167
[1] 17168
[1] 17169
```

Comment: The question is a FAQ, but the gist is that the attributes is dropped so the `Date` type becomes a simple integer.  For that reason I tend to write my loops over the indices rather than vector elements as you did in example one.  Right now I am forgetting what part the true culprit is but you just can't write the second loop over dates and retain the dates, sadly.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - seems like a good question - maybe post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I had to look it up: In the `for` loop, the `dates` object is coerced to a vector and _e.g._ `as.vector(dates)` shows what happens here.